# Отправка содержимого файла и информацию о файле одним запросом в Netty

Tags: java, netty

Я использую технологию zero-copy в Netty для отправки нескольких файлов из сервера клиенту. Но передо мной возникла проблема, мне нужно отправить одним запросом как содержимое файла, так и информацию о нем(к примеру название файла). Проблем бы не было если бы я не использовал технологию Zero-copy, тогда бы можно было просто считать файл в байтовый буфер, преобразовать всю нужную информацию о файле в байтовый массив и добавить этот байтовый массив в байтовый буфер и этот результирующий буфер отправить клиенту. Но к сожалению такое невозможно сделать, когда ты используешь технологию Zero-copy, так как при использовании этой технологии содержимое файла сразу считывается из диска в сокет минуя приложение и о каких-либо преобразованиях файла в самом приложении можно забыть. Есть ли у кого-нибудь идеи как одним запросом отправить содержимое и информацию о файле при этом используя технологию zero-copy?

Comment: Ну к примеру при считывании файла добавляйте в него дополнительно метаданные в заголовок, а на доугой стороне считывайте и удаляйте